# Angularjs controller and template encapsulation vs Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a state called *homeInside* and it's controller and template in my `angularjs` app (I'm using routing). There is a lot of elements, also a button with ng-click linked to *doSomething*. I have another state called *homeOutside*. This is completely is similar to first one, but *doSomething* do another task.

I don't want to duplicate anything. How can I do this with one single controller and template? Is it the reason that `Angular2` **components** comes into play for such scenarios (with it's constructor)?

Any idea would highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

In the first state:

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
    AuthService.logout();
}
```

In the second one:

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
    $state.go('dashboard');
}
```

All of the other parts are exactly the same.

Comment: Could you show us you code? And do you want the answer about AngularJS or Angular2?

Comment: sounds like a directive that get a function injected

Comment: @Raulucco yes, but we are not sure, right? We need a snnipet.

Comment: @RaphaelParreira yes we need some example code, i just through the idea so he can think about it

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for your responses. Please check edit part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a custom directive and passing in a function for doSomething

When creating the directive you use the '&' symbol to set a function as the directive parameter

Here is a good example that explain the usage
https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters

See the section where "add" is the function being passed in

Comment: It seems `directive` is the only way. But still need to duplicate the template. Any way, thanks.

Comment: do not duplicate the template use transaclude so you can inject the changing part of the template and encapsulate the common thing of the template

Answer (score 0):

In Angular v1.x You must make factory and inject it to you controllers where you want to make the same thing.
If you need example of factory I give it to you.

Comment: Thanks. But I think this one doesn't relate to factory or service. Please see edit part.